# Solve $10^x+11^x+12^x = 13^x+14^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find all real numbers $x$ for which $$10^x+11^x+12^x = 13^x+14^x.$$

I thought about taking the logarithm of both sides, but didn't see how that would help. How can we make the equation simpler?

Comment: Guess and check: $x=2$

Comment: One possible approach is to just check that $x = 2$ is a solution and use growth arguments to show that it's the unique solution

Comment: @CatalinZara, please make your comment into a solution.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti - Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hint: Divide by $13^x$ - the left hand side is decreasing and the right hand side is increasing; hence there is at most one solution. Since $x=2$ magically works, that is the unique solution.

Comment: Here we go: +1!

Comment: @AndreasCaranti - Thank you for the upvote.

Answer (score 5):

As [@CatalinZara](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2074127/307483) said, divide both sides by $13^x$:
$$\left(\frac{10}{13}\right)^x+\left(\frac{11}{13}\right)^x+\left(\frac{12}{13}\right)^x=1+\left(\frac{14}{13}\right)^x$$
For $0 < a < 1$, $a^x$ is decreasing, so the left side is a decreasing function. For $a > 1$, $a^x$ is increasing, so the right side is an increasing function. A decreasing and increasing function can only intersect once, so there is only one solution.

I tried $x=1$ and that didn't work. I tried $x=2$ and it did. Therefore, the solution is $x=2$.

Comment: @IQWANTER Sometimes, in math problems, you have to just see certain things and try stuff until it works. Here, I saw that all of the terms had an exponent of $x$, so I thought we need to divide by something to the $x^{\text{th}}$ power in order to cancel out one of the terms. First, I think I tried $14^x$, but that did not really do anything, even after graphing both sides. Then, I tried $13^x$ and that gave me a clear graph of one decreasing and one increasing function, so I decided to go with that approach.

Answer (score 1):

Main idea: dividing by $12^x$ gives an equivalent equation (I chose $12$ because it is the central value).

Let us show that the function defined by:

$$f(x):=\underbrace{(10/12)^x-(14/12)^x}_{g_1(x)}+1+\underbrace{(11/12)^x-(13/12)^x}_{g_2(x)}.$$

is strictly decreasing. In fact, it suffices to show that any function of the form:

$$h(x)=(1-a)^x-(1+a)^x \ \ \text{with} \ \ a>0$$

is strictly decreasing (indeed $g_1=h$ for $a=1/6$ and $g_2=h$ for $a=1/12$)

It is an almost immediate consequence of the fact that:

$$h'(x)=\underbrace{(1-a)^x}_{>0} \underbrace{ln(1-a)}_{<0} \ - \ \underbrace{(1+a)^x}_{>0} \underbrace{ln(1-a)}_{>0}$$

is negative.

As $x=2$ is a solution, it is thus the unique solution.