# Find all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for which $10^x+11^x+12^x = 13^x+14^x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> Find all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for which $$10^x+11^x+12^x = 13^x+14^x$$

Testing couple of values one can quickly see that $x=2$ satisfies the equation. Also dividing by $13^x$ the $LHS$ becomes a decreasing function of $x$ and the $RHS$ becomes an increasing function of $x$, hence $x=2$ is the only solution.

I tried the same problem using calculus, but couldn't get it to work. I tried subtracting the $RHS$ from both sides and then differentiating, but this didn't lead anywhere. Could this be solved with calculus?

Comment: If $x\lt 2$ then LHS is strictly greater than RHS and if $x\gt 2$ then LHS is strictly less than RHS. Therefore, $x=2$ is the only root.

Comment: @Daniel Try to divide both sides by some expression.

Comment: Divide by $12^x$.

Comment: @Vepir what is your basis for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solve $10^x+11^x+12^x = 13^x+14^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2074117/solve-10x11x12x-13x14x)